# How do I change the dialog selected text color in Eclipse Mars?

Tags: eclipse, themes

I recently switched from Eclipse Kelper to Mars, and I cannot see my selected text in **certain** dialogs anymore.

For example, the preferences input box works fine. Here is an example of some selected text in the search bar:

[image]

However, other dialogs, such as *find*, the selection is invisible. Either it's transparent or it's exactly the same as the background color.

[image]

- Why isn't this blue like the rest of text selections?
- (Where) Does Eclipse override this for certain dialogs?
- How do I fix this?